# java regex to mask ip address

Tags: java, regex, ip-address, mask

I want to write java program to mask the ip address present in input string

for e.g The Input string is "AAA192.168.110.*BBBB10.*"

Condition : Replace the ip address with 'X' character

I want to output as 
AAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXBBBXXXX

I tried to parse the string to replace the  ip address but i am not able to map the '*' as regex.

Can someone help me to write the reg-ex to replace the ip address in string?
Note: Number of characters to replace ('X') are equal to number of characters in ip address

for e.g 10.* with be replace by XXXX

There could other digits along with the ip address:

for e.g. "AAAA1710.20.*" . Here ip address to mask is "10.20.*". So output should be 
"AAAA17XXXXXXX"

So it should do masking for only ip that is needs to be masked. So for "AAA1710.20.*" , it should only remove "10.20.*"

Ip address that needs to be masked would be given as a input along with the input string to parse.

For the above example the ip address to parse would be "10.20.*"

The below code doesn't give me the required output:

String input = "AAAA99192.168.10.*CCCCCDDD10.*";

String m = input.replaceAll("[192.168.10.*]", "X").replace("[10.*]",
                "Y");

System.out.println(m);

//Output is AAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCCCCCDDDXXXX which incorrect . It replaces the 99 also which is incorrect . And also it should replace 10.* with 'YYYY' which is not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below code to maskout the numbers and dots,

```
String s = "AAA2110.20.*BB192.128.*";
String m = s.replaceAll("10\\.20\\.\\*", "XXXXXXX").replaceAll("192\\.128\\.\\*", "YYYYYYYYY");
System.out.println(m);
```

Output:

```
AAA21XXXXXXXBBYYYYYYYYY
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/z0amAU)

Comment: When i try to remove the ip address using below code. It doesn't give me the require output   String input = "AAAA99192.168.10.*CCCCCDDD10.*";
  String m = input.replaceAll("[192.168.11.*]", "X").replace("[10.*]",
    "Y");
  System.out.println(m);

Comment: could you post the ideone link you tried? And also your input isn't contains `11` then how it got replace?

Comment: HI Avinash, Thanks for the reply. My requirement is, it should only remove the ip address, but not other digits: so if input is AAA2110.20.*BB192.128.* and ip address to mask is 10.20.* and 192.128.* then it first step the output should be AAA21XXXXXXXBB192.128.* to remove 10.20.* AND in next step it should remove 192.128.* so output should be AAA21XXXXXXXBBXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Number 110 falls in one of the ipadress ranges then why are you trying to mask out the number starting from 10 why you don't 110?

Comment: Because it is the user input which would decide what ip address to mask So for the input  AAA2110.20.*BB192.128.*  , there could be other digits alongwith the ip address and the requirement is to mask the ip address 10.20.* and but not 110.20.*

Comment: Oh, we have to give it explicitly.so  `10.20.*` will be turned out to XXXXXXX and `192.128.*` to YYYYYYYYY. am i correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried it giving explicitly. But it doesn't work. I have updated the code which doesn't work in main question

Comment: wait i will get you soon.

Comment: But this solution still considers the digits to mask. What if my requirement is to remove ip address which is not present in input string  for e.g. String s = "AAA2110.20.*BB192.128.*"; and i want to remove 192.129.* which is not present in input string, but your given code still removes it, as it is not matching the exact ip string.

Comment: HI Avinash, I am grateful for your help. I just forgot to add one more requirement. where it says if ip to mask is 10.* and input string is  input = "AAAA10.20.*" Here ip in the input string should be removed as it falls under the ip to mask(10.*). Could you please help to get that?

Comment: I think it needs string comparison. Sorry i don't know too much about coding part. I only know regexes. You could ask it as a separate question by placing this question link on that question. It will help someothers to catch your needs quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
"([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

to find IP address.